# Getting validation issue using Fluent Validation on model class using MediatR

Tags: asp.net-core, validation, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation, mediatr

I am implementing a Fluent Validation while validating a UpdateBasketRequest:

```cs
public class UpdateBasketRequest : IRequest<UpdateBasketResponse>
{
   public string BasketId;
   public List<BasketItemDto> Items { get; set; }
}
```

- BasketItemDto

```cs
public class BasketItemDto
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; } 
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public Category? Category { get; set; }
}
```

- RequestHandler

```cs
public class UpdateBasketHandler : IRequestHandler<UpdateBasketRequest, UpdateBasketResponse>
{
    private readonly IBasketRepository basketRepository;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public UpdateBasketHandler(IBasketRepository basketRepository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.basketRepository = basketRepository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<UpdateBasketResponse> Handle(UpdateBasketRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
       var getCurrentBasket = await this.basketRepository.GetBasketAsync(request.BasketId);

       if (getCurrentBasket == null)
       {
           return new UpdateBasketResponse()
           {
               Error = new ErrorModel(ErrorType.NotFound)
           };
       }

            var newBasketItems = this.mapper.Map<UpdateBasketRequest, CustomerBasket>(request);

            var updatedBasket = await this.basketRepository.UpdateBasketAsync(newBasketItems);

            if (updatedBasket == null)
            {
                return new UpdateBasketResponse()
                {
                    Error = new ErrorModel(ErrorType.BadRequest)
                };
            }

            var response = new UpdateBasketResponse()
            {
                Data = this.mapper.Map<CustomerBasket, CustomerBasketDto>(updatedBasket)
            };

            return response;
        }
    }
```

- UpdateBasketValidator

```cs
public class UpdateBasketValidator : AbstractValidator<UpdateBasketRequest>
{
   public UpdateBasketValidator()
   {
      this.RuleFor(x => x.BasketId).NotNull().NotEmpty().WithMessage("Id cannot be empty or null");
   }
}
```

- BasketItemValidator:

```cs
public class BasketValidator : AbstractValidator<BasketItemDto>
{
   public BasketValidator()
   {
       RuleLevelCascadeMode = CascadeMode.Stop;

       this.RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotNull().NotEmpty().WithMessage("Id cannot be empty or null")
           .GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Id must be greater than 0");
       this.RuleFor(x => x.ImageUrl).NotNull().NotEmpty().WithMessage("Image Url cannot be empty or null");
       this.RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull().NotEmpty().WithMessage("Product name cannot be empty or null");
       this.RuleFor(x => x.ShortDescription).NotNull().NotEmpty().WithMessage("Short description cannot be empty or null");
       this.RuleFor(x => x.Quantity).NotNull().NotEmpty().WithMessage("Quantity cannot be empty or null")
           .GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Quantity must be greater than 0");
       this.RuleFor(x => x.Price).NotNull().NotEmpty().WithMessage("Price cannot be empty or null")
          .GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Price must be greater than 0");
     }
}
```

Now to the point. In BasketController I am passing id of the basket to request from route:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("{id}")]       
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateBasket([FromRoute] string id, [FromBody] UpdateBasketRequest request)
{
   request.BasketId = id;

   return await this.HandleRequest<UpdateBasketRequest, UpdateBasketResponse>(request);
}
```

But getting error (screenshot with debugging steps):

[image]

I suppose that I am getting that error because when I am passing UpdateBasketRequest BasketId is null and the object is then validated - so before assigning BasketId from route.

How to fix it in a proper way?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Detailed error message in modelState:

[image]

Comment: What is the detailed error message like?

Comment: @Chen In `UpdateBasketValidator`: `error CS0103: The name 'x' does not exist in the current context` in model state see Edit

Comment: Hi @luca88, the code seems to be fine. Have you tried reinstalling FluentValidation Nuget Package?

Comment: @Chen I have tried but same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think that cannot validate the request before id assigned to it from route.

I mean that I have request from body (but without Id or Id is null) -> then the request is validated -> id is null -> exception is thrown.

I don't know how to workaround this in propper way.